# Upload large file nginx + uwsgi

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

stack: flask 0.10 + uwsgi 1.4.5 + nginx 1.2.3

I can upload small files (<100k) through my application but larger ones fail.
uwsgi log shows:

> Invalid (too big) CONTENT_LENGTH. skip.

nginx log does not show anything useful.

I tried the following, without success:

- [nginx conf] client_max_body_size 0 or 20M
- [uwsgi conf] limit-post: 0 or 20000000
- [flask conf] MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH = 20000000

So my questions:

1. Is there a conf somewhere else i can change?
2. Is there a way of verifying the used options at runtime on uwsgi/nginx?

Comment: thanks to whoever suggested adding the MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH to Flask (and deleted the answer), i tried it, but it didn't help

Comment: That's, why I deleted it. Look at uwsgi [source](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/master/core/protocol.c#L429). It contains your error message. So I am pretty sure that `limit-post` isn't updated. Are you restart urwsgi ? Also check other uwsgi configs, maybe they contains `limit-post` to.

Comment: As you can see from uwsgi source: if no `limit-post`, then post size isn't limited in uwsgi. Check uwsgi process. On debian `/usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini` are also loaded with application config.

Comment: Yes, i did restart every time. I found the line in the uwsgi source as well, that's how i came to the limit stuff ;). Anyway, i checked for limit-post in all the confs, and ... you were right; the value was overwritten by another conf file. Thanks a lot for helping me debug. If you suggest it in an answer here, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem in uwsgi `limit-post` params. Look at [source](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/2.0.15/core/protocol.c#L429). This variable can be overridden by other configs. For example on debian config from `/usr/share/uwsgi/conf/default.ini` are also loaded.